# Access to function through this

Tags: javascript

```js
var Application;
(function (Application, PhotonSdk) {
    (function(Photon) {
        Photon.PeerManager = (function () {
            var $this;

            function PeerManager() {
                $this = this;
                this.currentStatus = PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connectClosed;
                
                this.peer = new PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer("ws://localhost:9090");
                this.peer.addPeerStatusListener(PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connecting, this._onConnecting);
                this.peer.addPeerStatusListener(PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connect, this._onConnect);
            }

            PeerManager.prototype.establishConnection = function() {
                this.peer.connect();
                console.log("Photon is establishing connection.");
            };

            PeerManager.prototype._onConnecting = function() {
                this.currentStatus = PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connecting;
                PeerManager.prototype._logConnectionState(this.currentStatus); //It work
            };

            PeerManager.prototype._onConnect = function () {
                this.currentStatus = PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connect;
                this._logConnectionState(this.currentStatus); //It isn't work :(
            };

            PeerManager.prototype._logConnectionState = function (state) {
                console.log("Photon connection is " + state + ". " + new Date().toTimeString());
            };

            return PeerManager;
        })();
    })(Application.Photon || (Application.Photon = {}));
})(Application || (Application = {}), Photon);
```

If i use `this._logConnectionState(this.currentStatus);`
i get `this._logConnectionState is not a function` error, but

```
PeerManager.prototype._logConnectionState(this.currentStatus);
```

or

```
$this._logConnectionState(this.currentStatus);
```

is work. Why it's happened and how i can do that access through `this` well doing?

Comment: When you use prototype, it is binded to an object. You will have to instantiate a object to use it. By default, `this` would point to global scope which will not have `_logConnectionState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that events _onConnecting and _onConnect are dispatching by PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer instance. Since you have added listeners here:

```
this.peer.addPeerStatusListener(PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connecting, this._onConnecting);
this.peer.addPeerStatusListener(PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connect, this._onConnect);
```

So functions are called with wrong this.

Try this:

```
function PeerManager() {
    $this = this;
    this.currentStatus = PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connectClosed;

    this.peer = new PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer("ws://localhost:9090");
    this.peer.addPeerStatusListener(PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connecting, this._onConnecting.bind(this));
    this.peer.addPeerStatusListener(PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connect, this._onConnect.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        PeerManager.prototype._onConnect = function () {
            this.currentStatus = PhotonSdk.PhotonPeer.StatusCodes.connect;
            this._logConnectionState(this.currentStatus); //It isn't work :(
        };
```

Your reference you used

```
_logConnectionState(this.currentStatus);
```

on seems to be this:

```
PeerManager.prototype._onConnect
```

and not that:

```
Peer Manager.prototype
```

basicly this refers to

```
 PeerManager.prototype._onConnect
```

and

```
this._logConnectionState
```

is the same as

```
PeerManager.prototype._onConnect._logConnectionState
```

wich is undefined because there is no local value /function for that reference.

As you see "this" only has a local context always being bound to the first object/function it can find while climbing up the scopes.